# DirectoryNotFoundException - Could Not Find Part of the Path

Tags: c#

I have a console application I built for myself to rename `.mp3` files I download. This application has worked flawlessly for quite a few months, but is all of a sudden tossing the titled exception at me with one particular directory. Not only is it this one directory, but is happening on only a select number of files - 3 of them were successfully renamed.

Here is my directory path and files:

[image]

Here is a snippet of the directory path where the exception is thrown, along with the exception's message:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string dir = @"M:\Temp Downloading Folder";

    var files = new DirectoryInfo(dir + @"\Gregory Alan Isakov Discography [2005 - 2013]\Rust Colored Stones").GetFiles("*.mp3").ToList();

    foreach (var item in files) {
        if (item.Name.Substring(0, 2).All(char.IsDigit)) {
            //string fullName = item.FullName.Replace("\\", "/");
            string newName = "Gregory Alan Isakov ";
            //exception thrown here
            File.Move(item.FullName, item.FullName.Replace(item.Name.Substring(0, 3), newName));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I tried changing the path to have `/` instead of `\\` with the same result.

According to the [Documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directorynotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when part of a file or directory cannot
>   be found.

However, the directory *is* found and correctly renamed the first 3 files (as depicted in the first image).

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Print value of this expression `item.FullName.Replace(item.Name.Substring(0, 3), newName)`.

Comment: May be that the folder name is too long? Try a shorter path on the same files and see if that produces the same error.

Comment: This is a common issue with getting files.  It search subfolders and will abort when any exception occurs.  To continue searching, you need to have an exception handler that will continue searching after the exception.  the only way of doing this correctly is to have a recursive function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bug in your code which changes the folder instead of the name of the file, running your code:

> C:\Temp Downloading Folder\Gregory Alan Isakov Discography [2005 -
>   2013]\Rust Colored Stones\05 - Only Ghosts.mp3

is changed to:

> C:\Temp Downloading Folder\Gregory Alan Isakov Discography [20**Gregory**
>   **Alan Isakov** - 2013]\Rust Colored Stones\Gregory Alan Isakov - Only
>   Ghosts.mp3

I let you debug and fix it yourself.

Comment: You sure? If this is just a bug I'll gladly delete the question, but I'm actually not getting that result.

Comment: Try outputting all the strings in your `File.Move(...` before that line and you will see.

Comment: Yup seeing that now. Seems to be related to the file path including `05`, same as the file's name. Nice catch! I'll actually leave this question up because others may fall into the same trap as I did.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to the length of your folder path. Shorten the length and try again.

[Microsoft's documentation on file naming and path lengths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) mentions that Windows imposes a 260 character limit for the total length of a path plus it's filename; this is referenced as the Maximum Path Length Limitation, quoted here for easier reference:

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
>   defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following
>   order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by
>   backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the
>   maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string"
>   where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for
>   the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for
>   visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)

However, if you are insistent on using the path names as-is, you can explore using the extended-length path name convention by prefixing paths with the "\?" notation.

> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to
>   permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of
>   32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components
>   separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the
>   lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation
>   function (this value is commonly 255 characters). To specify an
>   extended-length path, use the "\?\" prefix. For example, "\?\D:\very
>   long path".

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I led you down the garden path without fully realizing the dumb mistake I made. `Nima Ara`'s answer was actually correct, and I explained the issue it in my comment.

Comment: Updated answer. You may also run into this problem at some point, so I think it's worth posting. :)

Comment: Yes, please explain down-vote whoever did so. My response seems relevant, even if it wasn't the actual solution to the problem.

Comment: @Chase, I didn't down-vote but your answer is not relevant here, If that was the case the OP would receive a `PathTooLongException ` as opposed to the `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

Comment: Point taken. Thank you, Nima Ara, for elaborating. :)